# How to configure 3 new instances as dedicated master nodes in a running cluster with all its master and data nodes (Elasticsarch)?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

**Context:**

- We have an elastic search cluster with 10 nodes that are all configured as master: true and data true.
- Due to the characteristics of our infrastructure, all the nodes of a cluster (cluster of virtual machines in this case) take their configuration from a Github repository. In other words, each and every single node has the same configuration.
- From this group these 10 nodes that are configured as master: true, data: true, 3 are configured as master eligible.

**Steps we performed:**

- We turned off the 10 nodes that were being used by the cluster (all master and data true).
- We changed the configuration in the old nodes (let's call that group cluster of virtual machines: elastic-data) to data: true and the new nodes (let's call that new cluster of virtual machines elastic-master) to master: true.
- We set the new master as master elegible on both configurations (elastic-master and elastic-data nodes).
- We restarted the app.

**Problem we found:**

- The cluster started normally. The queries for cluster administration tasks (list of nodes, search for configurations, etc.) went very fast. With the previous configuration, most of the time, it did not respond. When we tried to perform a query to see the data we got: ***cannot allocate because all found copies of the shard are either stale or corrupt.***

After hours of trying to recover from that state, we decided to roll back the configuration, result cluster continues unstable.

A step-by-step guide on how to do this without leaving the cluster in the described state is highly appreciated.